# There is a 4 in my prime number list generated in Python

Tags: python

Here is my code.

```
#Prime numbers between 0-100
for i in range(2,100):
    flg=0
    for j in range(2,int(i/2)):
        if i%j==0:
            flg=1
            break
    if flg!=1:
        print(i)
```

And the output is

```
2
3
4 <-
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
```

I have no idea why there is this 4.
Pardon me if i made some noobish mistake, as i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Actually you don't need to check until `i / 2`, `int(math.sqrt(i)) + 1`is enough.

Comment: You don't need a flag, just put an `else` on the `for`. It will operate if there wasn't a `break`.

Comment: It's also pointless to check any even numbers so `range(3,100,2)` will save you 50% of work. Just remember to start with `[2]` or `print(2)` first.

Comment: @alko: I can assure you that none of the powers of 2 are odd, and won't be in a list of odd numbers generated by `range()`

Comment: @Wooble Yep, you're right. I looked on other range :)

Comment: You don't really need to go 2 by 2. The 'y' loop will break very fast when number is even. So you don't really save time that way.

Comment: Go for the sieve of Eratosthenes, if you really want to be more efficient. Unless you want to go for really large primes, this is a simple and very efficient algo.

Comment: @MatthieuW that is crazy, if you can reduce your input by half by adding a single parameter to the range function why would you not!?!? That is like spending $3000 on a new machine when the same model is sold next door for $1500.

Comment: @sudo-o Of course you can do it and it will save a some time. But not as much as you think, not the half by far especially if you compute more than in range 0-100. Just do the test for let's say 0-100000 and see if difference is more than 1%.

Comment: Ok for 0-100000 you save 13% by going 2 by 2. that's because computing square root and building the range takes about 24% of processing.

Comment: With the sieve of Eratosthenes, you divide processing time nearly by 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that range is not inclusive, i.e.

```
>>> range(2,2)
[]
```

So when you access 4, you don't check for divisors. Change for example to `range(2,int(i/2)+1)`

To speed up your calculation, you can use math.sqrt instead of /2 operation, for example as:

```
import math
```

and then

```
for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i)+1)):
```